# How to Know xml element is mandatory or not while parsing the xml using DOM parser?

Tags: xml, xsd

### Sample.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Sample" type="Test" /> 
<xs:complexType name="Test">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Dept" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

### Sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Sample>
<Name>John</Name>
<Dept>IT</Dept>
<Id>1234</Id>
</Sample>
```

The elements Name and Id are mandatory and element Dept is optional ,I can restrict condition in xsd but how  can know while parsing which element is mandatory or optional is there in any code for this ?

My question is how to get list of mandatory and optional xml elements   while parsing.